# Ruby deep hash looping?

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I have a large nested hash in the form below.  I need to loop through and pull out the name and url of each repository, but I can't seem to do that.  Any suggestions?

Code snippet:

```
repo_json = get_touched_repos()
repo_hash = JSON.parse(repo_json)
puts repo_hash.class
puts repo_hash['repositories'][0]['name']
```

The hash:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "repo",
      "username": "...",
      "name": "....",
      "owner": "...",
      "homepage": "",
      "description": "description",
      "language": "Java",
      "watchers": 2,
      "followers": 2,
      "forks": 1,
      "size": 
      "open_issues": 0,
      "score": 1.0,
      "has_downloads": true,
      "has_issues": true,
      "has_wiki": true,
      "fork": false,
      "private": false,
      "url": "http://my.domain.com/repo/name",
      "created": "2012-07-02T17:47:54Z",
      "created_at": "2012-07-02T17:47:54Z",
      "pushed_at": "2014-03-20T20:09:38Z",
      "pushed": "2014-03-20T20:09:38Z"
    },
    {....}
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each) method to do this

```
repo_hash['repositories'].each do |repo|
  puts repo['name']
  puts repo['url']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the names and the URLs in a hash:

```
name_url_pairs = repo_hash['repositories'].collect do |repo|
  { name: repo['name'], url: repo['url] }
end
```

**Update:** Returning a small hash with several extracted values.

Another approach to index by name:

```
name_hash = Hash[
  repo_hash['repositories'].collect do |repo|
    [ repo['name'], repo['url'] ]
  end
]
```

Comment: You forgot to change the first line.